# Using boto3, how to put a publicly-readable object into S3 (or DigitalOcean Spaces)

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

Can someone provide a complete example of the following: Use boto3 and Python (2.7) to upload a file from a desktop computer to DigitalOcean Spaces, such that the uploaded file would be publically readable from Spaces.

DigitalOcean says their Spaces API is the same as the S3 API.  I don't know if this is 100% true, but here is their API: https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces

I can do the file-upload, with the code below, but I can't find an example of how to specify the file be publically readable.  I do not want to make the entire Space (= S3 bucket) readable -- only the object.

```
import boto3
boto_session = boto3.session.Session()
boto_client = boto_session.client('s3',
                    region_name='nyc3',
                    endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                    aws_access_key_id='MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                    aws_secret_access_key='MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
boto_client.upload_file( FILE_PATHNAME, BUCKETNAME, OBJECT_KEYNAME )
```

Changing the last statement to the following did not work:

```
boto_client.upload_file( FILE_PATHNAME, BUCKETNAME, OBJECT_KEYNAME, 
                         ExtraArgs={ 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', } )
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add the acl after making the object   See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_acl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Vorsprung for his comment above.  The following works:

```
import boto3
boto_session = boto3.session.Session()
boto_client = boto_session.client('s3',
                    region_name='nyc3',
                    endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                    aws_access_key_id='MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                    aws_secret_access_key='MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

boto_client.upload_file( FILE_PATHNAME, BUCKETNAME, OBJECT_KEYNAME )
boto_client.put_object_acl( ACL='public-read', Bucket=BUCKETNAME, Key=OBJECT_KEYNAME )
```